# Sort stop working after enum values added

Tags: c#, sorting, enums

I have a imprmented sort method for a colection in my code and today i noticed something strange. When i tried to add new enum values to the enum the sort method crashed with this error.

> Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results. x: '',  x's type: 'Texture2D', IComparer: 'System.Array+FunctorComparer`1[Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D]'.

This seems really strange seens the sort is in now way dependent on earlyer result and all it should do is sort after the index of the enum insteed of alfabatic order.

Here is the code.

```
    availableTiles.Sort(CompareTilesToEnum);

    private static int CompareTilesToEnum(Texture2D x, Texture2D y)
    {
        int xValue = (int) (Enum.Parse(typeof(TileTyp), x.Name, true));
        int yValue = (int) (Enum.Parse(typeof(TileTyp), y.Name, true));
        if (xValue > yValue)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public enum TileTyp
    {
        Nothing = -1,
        Forest,
        Grass,
        GrassSandBottom,
        GrassSandLeft,
        GrassSandRight,
        GrassSandTop,
        Mounten,
        Sand,
        Snow,
        Water,
        GrassSandTopLeft,
        GrassSandAll,
        GrassSandBottomLeft,
        GrassSandBottomRightLeft,
        GrassSandBottomRightTop,
        GrassSandBottomTopLeft,
        GrassSandRightLeft,
        GrassSandRightTop,
        GrassSandRightTopLeft,
        GrassSandBottomRight,
        GrassSandBottomTop
    }
```

The values i added was

```
    GrassSandBottomRight,
    GrassSandBottomTop
```

Comment: if A and B are equal, your code returns -1 for both `A>B` and `B>A`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison *never* returns 0 - even if the values are equal. Any reason you don't just ask `int.CompareTo` to compare the values?

```
private static int CompareTilesToEnum(Texture2D x, Texture2D y)
{
    int xValue = (int) (Enum.Parse(typeof(TileTyp), x.Name, true));
    int yValue = (int) (Enum.Parse(typeof(TileTyp), y.Name, true));
    return xValue.CompareTo(yValue);
}
```

Simpler and more importantly, it should actually *work* :)

Comment: Unless it's possible for a null `Texture2D` to be in the collection sorted, in which case you'll throw `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly states, your comparer is broken.

You need to return `0` if the values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

There are some rules you must follow with any comparison method:

1. If A == B, then B == A (return zero both times).
2. If A < B and B < C, then A < C.
3. If A < B, then B > A
4. A == A (return zero if compared with itself).

(Note, the `==` above means that nether `<` nor `>` is true. It is permissable for two objects to be equivalent in a sort-order without being true for a corresponding `Equals`. We could for instance have a rule that sorted all strings containing numbers in numerical order, put all other strings and the end, but didn't care about what order those other strings were in).

These rules follow for any language (they're not programming rules, they're logic rules), there is a .NET specific one too:

5: If A != null, then A > null.

You're breaking all of the first four rules. Since `Texture2D` is a reference type you risk breaking rule 5 too (will throw a different exception though).

You're also lucky that .NET catches it. A different sort algorithm could well have crashed with a more confusing error or fallen into an infinite loop as it e.g found that item 6 was reported as greater than item 7 and swapped them, then soon after found that item 6 was reported as greater than item 7 and swapped them, then soon after found...

```
private static int CompareTilesToEnum(Texture2D x, Texture2D y)
{
    //Let's deal with nulls first
    if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))//both null or both same item
      return 0;
    if(x == null)
      return -1;
    if(y == null)
      return 1;
    //Enum has a CompareTo that works on integral value, so why not just use that?
    return Enum.Parse(typeof(TileTyp), x.Name, true)).CompareTo(Enum.Parse(typeof(TileTyp), y.Name, true)));
}
```

(This assumes a failure in the parsing is impossible and doesn't have to be considered).